# Knuth summation clarification

Tags: limits, summation

I am reading Chapter 1 Section 1.2.3 of TAOCP Volume 1 Ed.03 (p. 27) and I came across the following: 
$$\sum_{R(j)} a_j =\left(  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} 
 R(j) \\
 0\le j\le n 
\end{smallmatrix}} a_j \right) + \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} 
 R(j) \\ 
 0\le j\le n 
\end{smallmatrix}} a_j \right) \tag 3
$$
which Knuth states is the precise meaning of: 
$$\sum_{R(j)} a_j \tag 2$$ 
provided that both limits exist.  Knuth continues: If either limit fails to exist, the infinite sum is *divergent*; it does not exist.  Otherwise, it is *convergent* (p. 28).

I do not understand the "precise meaning" of equation $(2)$ because there does not seem to be a difference between the two limits in equation $(3)$.  Of course, this is the third edition, so I doubt this is a typo.  I searched the errata and found no reference to this.  I searched https://math.stackexchange.com/ and did not find a question about this.

How am I supposed to interpret equation $(3)$?  How can one of these limits exist and not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second limit on the righthand side of $(3)$ is supposed to read

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{R(j)\\-n\le j<0}}a_j\;.$$

This is how it reads in the [copy of the third edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=x9AsAwAAQBAJ) offered by Google Books.